# Вывод отсортированных строк из файла

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, сортировка, потоки-данных

Дан файл с результатами игры с информацией об имени и времени игры примерно такой:

```
6/Maksim
1/Andrey
10/Dmitriy
15/Alexey
8/Liza
```

То есть у меня есть игра, в которой основная цель - продержаться как можно дольше. Кто продержался дольше - тот якобы самый лучший игрок. После каждой сессии игры запрашиваесть имя игрока, и эта информация записывается в файл `Top.txt` в следующем формате:

```
количество_секунд/имя_игрока
```

Нужно вывести в консоль **отсортированные** результаты. Я, честно говоря, даже не имею идей, как это сделать.
Исходя из данных выше, нужно чтобы в консоль вывелось вот это:

```
15/Alexey
10/Dmitriy
8/Liza
6/Maksim
1/Andrey
```

Comment: `sort -n -r < datafile`, только `sort` - GNU'шный...

Comment: А без GNU'шного ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("data");
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s))
        v.push_back(s);
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const string& s1, const string& s2)
         { return stoi(s1) > stoi(s2); });
    for(auto s: v)
        cout << s << endl;
}
```

Для супердревностей с недоделками (проверял на Open Watcom 1.9)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool compare(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    return atoi(s1.c_str()) > atoi(s2.c_str());
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("data");
    char buf[256];
    while(in.getline(buf,256))
        v.push_back(buf);
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);
    for(vector<string>::iterator s = v.begin(); s != v.end(); ++s)
        cout << s->c_str() << endl;
}
```

Comment: [Вот так у меня вышло](http://imgur.com/b6INmPd)

Comment: Ну, это у вас какой-то особо древний компилятор... Ладно, сейчас напишу для древности.

Comment: Смотрите для особо древних...

Comment: Code::Blocks 16.01 разве считается древним?)

Comment: Да, сработало для "древних". Спасибо большое. Буду разбираться детально.

Comment: Code::Blocks - не компилятор, а среда. А какой к нему компилятор прикручен... А может, компилятор и ничего :), а у вас просто не указано в настройках C++11 использовать.