# Вывод на экран отсортированных строк из файла

Tags: массивы, файлы, сортировка, потоки-данных, вектор

У меня есть игра, в которой основная цель - продержаться как можно дольше. Кто продержался дольше - тот якобы самый лучший игрок. После каждой сессии игры запрашиваесть имя игрока, и эта информация записывается в файл top.txt в следующем формате:

```
количество_секунд/имя_игрока
```

Чтобы было понятно, файл выглядит вот так:

[image: screen]

Нужно вывести в консоль **отсортированные** результаты. Я пробовал `sort` при работе с `vector` вот так:

```
vector<string> v;
ifstream in("top.txt");
char buf[256];
while(in.getline(buf,256))
v.push_back(buf);
std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
std::reverse(v.begin(),v.end());
for(vector<string>::iterator s = v.begin(); s != v.end(); ++s) 
cout << s->c_str() << endl;
```

То есть **сортируем**, **переворачиваем** и выводим на экран все элементы. Казалось бы, да? Но результат получается не таким, каким его хотелось бы видеть:

[image: result]

Результаты с 127, 1223, 11 и 10ю секундами должны быть выше чем, например, 9.

Это мой второй аналогичный вопрос. [Первый тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/663023/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0). Предложенный вариант работал только тогда, когда весь код располагался в одном файле **main.cpp**, разбив  программу на пару классов получил ошибки. Тот же самый код, за исключением того, что использовалась функция для сравнения: `sort(v.begin(),v.end(),compare);`
А сама функция такая:

```
bool Menu::compare(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    return atoi(s1.c_str()) > atoi(s2.c_str());
}
```

Код выше в Menu.cpp, прототип функции в Menu.h:

```
bool compare(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2);
```

Очень долго компилятор ругался на string, в итоге гугл дал совет, что надо использовать std. И вот что компилятор выдаёт на этот способ сортировки:

[image: error]

**Прошу подскажите мне простой способ сортировки, либо мой косяк, почему вылетают такие ошибки непонятные. Всё что надо по коду предоставлю.**

Да, если что: Code::Blocks 16.01, GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: Распарси строку в структуру и сортируй вектор структур.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что строки сравниваются посимвольно, а вы хотите сравнивать числа. Решением может быть сравнение чисел, с которых начинаются строки, что вы в принципе и пытаетесь сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto comparator = [](string s0, string s1) {
        int first_number0 = atoi(s0.c_str());
        int first_number1 = atoi(s1.c_str());
        return first_number0 > first_number1;
    };

    vector<string> lines;
    ifstream in("top.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    sort(lines.begin(), lines.end(), comparator);
    for (string line : lines) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```